# Linking a contact page to the home page in HTML5

Tags: html, css

I am using note pad ++. I have created a separate sheet for my contact us page called Contact us, I need to link it to my main page called adventures. All files are stored in the same folder.

I have successfully linked my CSS page and another page in the same tool bar using the below code

```html
<lINK href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<nav>
  <a href="adventures.html"> Vietnam</a><br>
  <a href="madagascar.html"> Madagascar</a><br>
  <a href="Contact us.html"> Contact us </a><br>

</nav>
```

But it's not working for the contact page.

Comment: try "/pagename.html", aslo this has nothing to do with css

Comment: is your html page actually named `Contact us.html`? Try `Contact%20us.html` or get rid of white space in name. Usually file names are with underscore or minus sign. E.g. `contact-us.html` or `contact_us.html`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Wrong :

```
<a href="Contact us.html"> Contact us </a><br>
```

Correct :

```
<a href="Contact-us.html"> Contact us </a><br>
```

- Dont add any space between contact and us.
- Make it Contactus.html or Contact_us.html or Contact-us.html.
- Even you can add white space but that is not a good coding practice.

Comment: Actually you can have link with whitespaces